# What options Do I have over double quotes for PassPhrase in GPG Decrypt?

Tags: gnupg

I'm having a hard time finding a substitute to double quotes for passphrase decrypting a file:

```
gpg --passphrase-file "this is a sentence passphrase"} --batch -d --output myfile.txt myfile.gpg
```

I am writing a program to wrap gpg interactino and working with double quotes is messing it up (I can't remove escape \" but this is not the questions...)

Is there a way to replace double quotes with something else when the passphrase is a sentece with space characters?

thanks

Comment: This is a question which just asks how to quote/escape special characters inside the shell. Not related to information security at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either use single quotes `'passphrase"withquotes'` (but then you are not allowed to have single quotes within the passphrase any more). Alternatively, you'll have to *escape* the quote character (and other characters with special meanings): `"passphrase\"withquotes"`.

You explain you're writing some program which requires passphrase handling. All reasonable programming languages should have some function or library which brings readily-built functions for bash escaping.

Anyway, you should **never pass the passphrase as parameter** (you're using the wrong argument anyway, have a look at the `--passphrase...` options in the GnuPG man page): all other users on the system can read all processes' command lines including the secret passphrase! Instead, use `--passphrase-fd 0` and attach your application to GnuPG's STDIN (like you'd do with a pipe on the command line), and pass the passphrase as input.

Using GnuPG 2.1 and upwards, you cannot use the `--passphrase...` options any more without hassles. Have a look at ["Why does GPGME / GnuPG use pinentry for password input?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35064312/695343) for further discussion.